# Adding axis labels next to the bars within a horizontal barplot in R

Tags: r

With the code below. First I tried to have every single alternative displayed by the y axis horizontally. However, the output is chopped (see picture), it seems like the space next to the y axis can only contain so much space, I tried saving it or zooming it but it still didn't work. So I thought I can put the labels next to the bar in the plot. ChatGPT suggested the text function (see code below), it kind of worked but the text does not align with the bars and I am struggling to change that.

```
rel_freq <- function(x) {
  (x/sum(x))*100
}

alternatives <- c("District heating"= 13,"Heat pump"= 10,"Solar thermal collector"= 6, "Pellet stove"= 6,
                  "Wood stove"= 4, "Geothermal" = 3, "Thermal energy storage" = 2, "Sustainable gas boiler" = 2,
                  "Biogas boiler" = 1, "Electric boiler" = 1, "Wood fireplace" = 1)

barplot(rel_freq(alternatives), xlab="Relative frequency (%)",
        col = c("coral2"), border=NA, horiz = TRUE, las = 1, beside = TRUE, xlim = c(0,29))
text(x = rel_freq(alternatives), y = 1:length(alternatives), 
     labels = names(alternatives), pos = 4, cex = 0.7)

box(col="black")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution contains two different approaches. First, the left margin ins extended with `par(mar, .....)`.

To place labels directly besides of the bars, we need compatible y-coordinates, as `barplot` uses a scale different from 1 per bar. Fortunately, these values are returned as a vector, that we can assign to a variable, e.g. `bp` and use in `text`.

```r
rel_freq <- function(x) {
  (x/sum(x))*100
}

par(mar=c(4,10,1,1)+.1)

alternatives <- c("District heating" = 13,"Heat pump" = 10,
  "Solar thermal collector" = 6, "Pellet stove" = 6,
  "Wood stove" = 4, "Geothermal" = 3, "Thermal energy storage" = 2,
  "Sustainable gas boiler" = 2, "Biogas boiler" = 1,
  "Electric boiler" = 1, "Wood fireplace" = 1)

bp <- barplot(rel_freq(alternatives), xlab = "Relative frequency (%)",
        col = c("coral2"), border=NA, horiz = TRUE, las = 1,
        beside = TRUE, xlim = c(0, 35))

text(x = rel_freq(alternatives), y = bp, 
     labels = names(alternatives), pos = 4, cex = 0.7)

box(col = "black")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the margin on the left of the page. To do this set the graphic parameter `mar` using `par`:

```r
par(mar = c(5, 12, 2, 2))

barplot(rel_freq(alternatives), xlab="Relative frequency (%)",
        col = c("coral2"), border=NA, horiz = TRUE, las = 1, beside = TRUE, 
        xlim = c(0,29))
```

[image]

Or, you could use `ggplot`, which will fit everything in for you without you having to specify a margin:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(name = names(alternatives), values = rel_freq(alternatives)),
       aes(x = values, y = factor(name, name))) +
  geom_col(fill = 'coral2', width = 0.7) +
  labs(y = NULL, x = 'Relative frequency (%)') +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line())
```

[image]